# Issue loading 'dplyr' packages

Tags: r, dplyr

All

I am trying to install and load 'dplyr' packages so that I can start to manipulate data at ease. Here is what I did and the error messages I got.

> install.packages("dplyr")
>   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/YingHaw/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/dplyr_0.4.1.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 2596780 bytes (2.5 MB)
>   opened URL
>   downloaded 2.5 MB

package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\YingHaw\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp4KMRy3\downloaded_packages

> library("dplyr")
>   Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : 
>     cannot open file 'C:/Users/YingHaw/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/R/Rcpp.rdb': No such file or directory
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’

Can someone tell me what possibly went wrong?

Anson

Comment: try re-installing Rcpp first?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're facing issues in installing the dplyr package. Better remove both the packages plyr and dplyr (if already installed)and then try again installing it. if not better update your rstudio version and then try installing it

I have previously faced these issues but after removing and reinstalling it, that works.